# How to iterate BeautifulSoup to get all the actions (links) from all the forms on a site?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote the following to scrape actions from forms to save me clicking one at a time

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://website.com/login'
    EMAIL = ''
    PASSWORD = ''
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": 
    "https://website.com/"})
    page = c.get('https://website.com/dashboard')


parser = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
forms = parser.find('form').get('action')
```

When i run this i only get the result from the first form.
If i can iterate this to get all the results that one solution.

I can change the find to

```
parser.find_all('form')
```

and it will return all the forms, but instead of useable links i get

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://website.com/action" method="GET">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="action"/>
</form>
```

It stores these in a python list, so if these can be iterated over to remove everything except the url (they are always the same format, slightly different length url but the stuff before and after is always the same.) thats another solution

If i try to use

```
parser.find_all_next('form').get('action')
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scrape.py", line 16, in <module>
forms = parser.find_all_next('form').get('action')
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1807, in __getattr__
"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a singleitem. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: Please, update your question with a link.

Comment: A link to what? I can't link the live site.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question and give some example input/output, but the best would be a URL to a website :P I have no idea what you mean by "stripping a list to leave just a list".

Comment: ok i edited to provide all the code and examples sanitised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to loop over `parser.find_all('form')` and get the `action` attribute for each element and store it in a list; which can be done using *list comprehension*.

```
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://website.com/login'
    EMAIL = ''
    PASSWORD = ''
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(email=EMAIL, password=PASSWORD)
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": 
    "https://website.com/"})
    page = c.get('https://website.com/dashboard')    

parser = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
forms = [f.get('action') for f in parser.find_all('form')]
```

The list of all the URLs is stored in the `forms` variable.